# How is a django app different from a python package?

Tags: python, django

If I create a normal python package (with `__init__.py`), instead of `manage.py startapp` won't I still be able to use it like a django app.?

Comment: You will be able. Don't forget to include it in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django app is actually a python package that follows the Django convention. Django-admin startapp is just a helper command to create the files in that convention. If you want to create an app without using startapp, then can create a folder and create `__init__.py` file and create the necessary files(for views and models). And you should include it in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use it as a django app. Django is a web framework, hence its main aim is to allow their users to focus on their applications rather than to make them hard-code every single bit of information.